# What day and year was the first public & general confession held in the Church of England?

Tags: social-history, reformation

Was it proscribed in the act of supremacy of 1532?

Comment: The [Act of Supremacy](http://www.britainexpress.com/History/tudor/act-of-supremacy.htm0w as passed in 1534, not 1532.  The text is available from that link and it does not mention confession.  Please do preliminary research before asking.

Comment: FWIW, this question has been answered at [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48475/what-day-and-year-was-the-first-public-general-confession-held-in-the-church-o) so I suggest that it be closed here.

Comment: It has not, yet, been selected as accepted, so why the rush to close here?

Comment: Having been answered elsewhere is not a close reason for History.SE.

Comment: I believe you mean *prescribed - recommended ... as being beneficial*, not *proscribed - forbidden, especially by law*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - also, it should be tagged "Religion" and "England".

Answer (score 1):

The Act of Supremacy occurred in 1534. The first time ANY part of the Mass was said in English was in 1548, but I'm darned right now if I recall which part! I think it was the General Confession actually. The Book of Common Prayer was not used until 1549.